# Find all rows with cell matching range values, copy to new worksheet named by value

Tags: excel, vba

I have to pull reporting on customer data that includes multiple currencies. Instead of being formatted as a single item per line with multiple currency column, each currency that applies to an item gets its own row, so the data may end up looking like:

[image: Screenshot of an Excel data table]

What I need to do with it is break it out to different worksheets based on the Currency Code. I've currently gotten my VBA code to the point where I can identify a list of unique currency code values, create new worksheets per value, and then copy data to those worksheets, but I'm getting stuck on getting it to copy the RIGHT data to the new worksheets. Currently it just copies the same data to each sheet, which is to say it would copy all of the rows for "AUD - Australian Dollar" to each of the newly created worksheet.

Link to dummy file: https://www.dropbox.com/s/eotyqdi1wzvuzrf/Test%20Book.xlsm?dl=0

I'm putting my full code block first in case someone sees something wrong with it outside of where I think the issue is, then I'm putting a second block of just the code I think is the problem

**Full Code**

```
Sub CopyData()
''    -----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
''    Create new worksheet to store currency list
''    -----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    Sheets.Add.Name = "Currencies"
'
''    -----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
''   Find the unique currency values
''    -----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    Dim s1 As Worksheet, s2 As Worksheet
    Set s1 = Sheets("Metadata")
    Set s2 = Sheets("Currencies")
    s1.Range("A1:F300000").Sort Key1:=Range("C1"), Order1:=xlAscending, Header:=xlYes
    s1.Range("C:C").Copy s2.Range("A1")
    s2.Range("A:A").RemoveDuplicates Columns:=1, Header:=xlNo
    s2.Rows(1).Delete

'    -----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
'   Find all rows matching currency from raw data and copy to new sheet named by currency
'    -----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Dim strArray As Variant
Dim wsSource As Worksheet
Dim wsDest As Worksheet
Dim NoRows As Long
Dim DestNoRows As Long
Dim I As Long
Dim test As Integer
Dim J As Integer
Dim rngCells As Range
Dim rngFind As Range
Dim Found As Boolean
Dim DataRange As Range
Dim cell As Range

'    Determine the data you want stored
      Set DataRange = Sheets("Currencies").Range("A1:A2")

'    Resize Array prior to loading data
      ReDim strArray(DataRange.Cells.Count)

'    Loop through each cell in Range and store value in Array
      For Each cell In DataRange.Cells
        strArray(x) = cell.Value
        x = x + 1
      Next cell

'    Print values to Immediate Window (Ctrl + G to view)
      For x = LBound(strArray) To UBound(strArray)
        Debug.Print strArray(x)
      Next x

    Set wsSource = Sheets("Metadata")

    NoRows = wsSource.Range("A300000").End(xlUp).Row
    DestNoRows = 1

    For Each cell In DataRange

        Set wsDest = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets.Add
        ActiveSheet.Name = cell.Value

        For I = 1 To NoRows

            Set rngCells = wsSource.Range("A" & I & ":Z" & I)
            Found = False

            For J = 0 To UBound(strArray)
                Found = Found Or Not (rngCells.Find(strArray) Is Nothing)
            Next J

            If Found Then
                rngCells.EntireRow.Copy wsDest.Range("A" & I - 1)
                DestNoRows = DestNoRows + 1
            End If

        Next I

    Next cell

ActiveWorkbook.Save

End Sub
```

**Just the bit I think is wonky**

```
'    -----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
'   Find all rows matching currency from raw data and copy to new sheet named by currency
'    -----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Dim strArray As Variant
Dim wsSource As Worksheet
Dim wsDest As Worksheet
Dim NoRows As Long
Dim DestNoRows As Long
Dim I As Long
Dim test As Integer
Dim J As Integer
Dim rngCells As Range
Dim rngFind As Range
Dim Found As Boolean
Dim DataRange As Range
Dim cell As Range

'    Determine the data you want stored
      Set DataRange = Sheets("Currencies").Range("A1:A2")

'    Resize Array prior to loading data
      ReDim strArray(DataRange.Cells.Count)

'    Loop through each cell in Range and store value in Array
      For Each cell In DataRange.Cells
        strArray(x) = cell.Value
        x = x + 1
      Next cell

'    Print values to Immediate Window (Ctrl + G to view)
      For x = LBound(strArray) To UBound(strArray)
        Debug.Print strArray(x)
      Next x

    Set wsSource = Sheets("Metadata")

    NoRows = wsSource.Range("A300000").End(xlUp).Row
    DestNoRows = 1

    For Each cell In DataRange

        Set wsDest = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets.Add
        ActiveSheet.Name = cell.Value

        For I = 1 To NoRows

            Set rngCells = wsSource.Range("A" & I & ":Z" & I)
            Found = False

            For J = 0 To UBound(strArray)
                Found = Found Or Not (rngCells.Find(strArray) Is Nothing)
            Next J

            If Found Then
                rngCells.EntireRow.Copy wsDest.Range("A" & I - 1)
                DestNoRows = DestNoRows + 1
            End If

        Next I

    Next cell
```

Comment: A slightly different way to approach this, and maybe shorter - get the list of unique currencies in an array or dictionary. Then loop through the array/dictionary, *filter* the original sheet based on each currency, copy visible cells to the newly added sheet.

Comment: If you are pulling this data from a database you could break it down using queries instead. It would be much easier to return each dataset from the DB using a `WHERE "Currency Code" = "BGN -Lev"`. You could have a PowerBI query on each tab and it would automatically update every time you open the spreadsheet.

Comment: @BigBen - I'm already most of the way to that, but the loop through the array doesn't seem to work since it's grabbing the same data each time.

Comment: @HackSlash - Unfortunately I'm stuck with what the system spits out. I'm not a DB admin and don't have direct access to run custom queries, so I've got to use what the powers that be have given us

Comment: @IDabble you're not using a *filter* though, are you? That was my proposal.

Comment: 2nd the `dictionary` idea. Currency code into an `array` and loop thru abd populate a dictionary with unique values. then you could use `AdvFilter`

Comment: @BigBen I am not. I'm not actually familiar with how best to do that. Can you add a code snippet for how you'd do it in the answers and I'll give it a try.

Comment: It's just using `Range.AutoFilter`

Answer (score 0):

Based on the feedback I got in the comments I refactored to loop through, filter, and then copy only visible cells. I also change the column definitions to user input boxes, which is why the ranges look significantly different than the original

```
For Each cell In DataRange

    code = cell.Value
    wsSource.Range("A1").AutoFilter Field:=xCurrNum, Criteria1:=code
    Set wsDest = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets.Add
    ActiveSheet.Name = cell.Value
    wsSource.Range(xPub & "2:" & xPub & "300000").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Copy Destination:=wsDest.Range("A2")
    wsSource.Range(xIsbn & "2:" & xIsbn & "300000").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Copy Destination:=wsDest.Range("C2")
    wsSource.Range(xPrice & "2:" & xPrice & "300000").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Copy Destination:=wsDest.Range("E2")
    wsSource.Range(xDiscount & "2:" & xDiscount & "300000").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Copy Destination:=wsDest.Range("F2")
Next cell
```